# Passing data from service to component everytime parameter changes

Tags: angular

I'm detecting in my detail component if url parameter changes:

```
this.route.params
  .subscribe(
    (params: Params) => {
      console.log('route parameter changed');
      this.id = +params['id'];
      this.dataStorageDervice.getMeldunek(this.id);
    }
  );
```

And in my REST service i have a method :

```
getMeldunek(id: number) { 
  this.http.get('http://192.168.0.154:8080/api/rezerwacja/getPrzyjazdy/rezerwacja?id=' + id)
    .map((response: Response) => {
      const meldunek: Meldunek = response.json();
      return meldunek;
    });
}
```

How can I connect these two and pass response to my component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add the missing return statement, pointed out in [AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltds answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46976150/2521893):

   ```
   getMeldunek(id: number) { 
     return this.http
       .get('...' + id)
       .map((response: Response) => { 
           const meldunek: Meldunek = response.json(); 
           return meldunek; 
     });    
   }
   ```
2. Try using `mergeMap` to use the result from the first `Observable` (this.route.params) in your second `Observable` (`this.dataStorageDervice.getMeldunek`). Then `subscribe` to that:

   ```
   export class YourComponent {
     ngOnInit() {
         this.route.params
          .mergeMap((params: Params) => {
            console.log('route parameter changed');
            this.id = +params['id'];
            return this.dataStorageDervice.getMeldunek(this.id);
         }).subscribe(meldunek => {
           // do something with your meldunek
         });
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the `return` statement:

```
getMeldunek(id: number) { 
  return this.http
    .get('http://192.168.0.154:8080/api/rezerwacja/getPrzyjazdy/rezerwacja?id=' + id)
    .map((response: Response) => { 
      const meldunek: Meldunek = response.json(); 
      return meldunek; 
    });    
}
```

Comment: yeah so I will be returning observable (http.get) to my component? can I just return a data, not observable?

Comment: @Ziomski definitly easier and recommended to return an observable and let your component do the subscription

Comment: @FredrikLundin could you link me an example, please?